# How to add pagination after using hook_views_post_execute() to modify $view->result?

Tags: 7, views, paging

I have successfully used `hook_views_post_execute()` to remove results I do not want from `$views->result`.

Now, however, I need to paginate the remaining results.

The code in my `hook_views_post_execute()` requires the full result set to work. If I edit the view in the admin interface and set it to 10 items per page with full pagination, the `$views->result` in `hook_views_post_execute()` will only include 10 items, so my code doesn't function properly.

It looks like I need to use `hook_views_pre_render()` to set up the pagination, but I'm not sure how.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I would suggest using hook_views_query_alter() if possible to alter the $query to remove items. All features would then work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually realized that `hook_views_query_alter()` was the appropriate hook, but it wasn't working because this view utilizes Search API. Turns out `hook_search_api_views_query_alter()` is a hook specifically for altering the query when using Search API.

I used this hook to add a condition to the view query before it is executed. This allowed me to turn pagination back on in the admin panel and have it work as anticipated.

```
function mymodule_search_api_views_query_alter(view &$view, SearchApiViewsQuery &$query) {
  if ($view->name === 'my_view_name') {
    // Do some stuff to get the nids I'd like to allow in my result set.
    $nids = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

    // Add the condition to the existing query.
    $view->query->condition('nid', $nids, 'IN');
  }
}
```